# Download a large file on Uno Platform WebAssembly

Tags: cors, webassembly, uno-platform

I am trying to download some large files on my Uno WebAssembly application. However, all of my downloads failed because of CORS.

I have tried using http://cors.bridged.cc/, however, although the site works for small queries and web pages, it does not seem to work for files larger than 500kB.

So are there any CORS proxies that can handle large files? Or are there any **workarounds** for Uno platform in Wasm?

#### My first attempt:

I tried to send requests for small chunks of 8192 bytes. Although it passes in the online app and on Reqbin, and also succeeds when invoking `fetch` in the console, trying to send the request using C# fails with CORS error.

#### Edit:

- I am not looking for software, books, libraries, and stuff. I am looking for a WORKAROUND, which might involve libraries, servers, or complicated coding. I am finding ANY method possible.

#### My second attempt:

Asking for chunks is right, it worked. My first attempt failed because of unrelated bugs in my C# code. However, this workaround don't work for all files, as many files do not accept HTTP range requests.

Comment: To the reviewers: Please don't close an already answered question. The question is very much valid, if you know the context. "Not suitable for this site" is not a welcoming comment for such a question. @eyllanesc

Comment: Agree with @JérômeLaban, there is nothing off-topic about this question, it is very valid and relevant

Answer (score 3):

As far as Uno and WebAssembly are concerned, available techniques are the same that are available for any JavaScript SPA application. Free CORS-enabling proxies are generally locked down for cost and privacy concerns.

You may ask for the site owner to make its resources CORS-enabled, or make a proxy yourself, using azure functions or similar services (which you'll need to lock down as well for the same reason free services are doing it).